# Returning my object into a HashSet

Tags: java, collections

I'm almost completely blind, and I'm trying to learn Java. I'm telling you this because I've had a difficult time understanding concepts well, because of my disability.

**My problem**:
In this particular class, I'm returning an object that I'd like to be stored somewhere to later be called. I'm unfamiliar with `Collections`, but I believe (I think?) a `HashSet` is the type of `Set` I'd like to implement here. Would I be able to do this, and call this collection of objects from a different class once its created?

I'm very new to Java so I'm not quite sure if I've explained my problem effectively. Please don't hesitate to ask for clarification!

**Important:** I'm not to allow any duplicates of `airCode`, would HashSet handle that in some way?

```
public class A8AirlineAircraftData {


private String airName; //these are all showing a warning saying 'Field ____ can be final'
private String airCode;
private String airCraft;
private int firstClass;
private int busiClass;
private int econClass;
//public String toStringAirLine(){return "airname is:" + airName + ", aircode is: "+airCode;}


public A8AirlineAircraftData(String airName, String airCode, String airCraft, int firstClass, int busiClass, int econClass) {
    this.airName = airName;
    this.airCode = airCode;
    this.airCraft = airCraft;
    this.firstClass = firstClass;
    this.busiClass = busiClass;
    this.econClass = econClass;
} 

public static A8AirlineAircraftData AddAirline(Scanner sc) {
    sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the Airline name:");
    String airName = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter the Airline code:");
    String airCode = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the Delta Aircraft:");
    String airCraft = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the first class seat capacity:");
    int firstClass = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the business class seat capacity:");
    int busiClass = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the economy class seat capacity:");
    int econClass = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Airline name: " + airName);
    System.out.println("Airline code: " + airCode);
    System.out.println("Delta Aircraft: " + airCraft);
    //Splitting the first word from the rest of the string
    String arr[] = airCraft.split(" ", 2);
    String firstWord = arr[0];
    System.out.println(firstWord + " first class seat capacity: " + firstClass);
    System.out.println(firstWord + " business class seat capacity: " + busiClass);
    System.out.println(firstWord + " economy class seat capacity: " + econClass);
    //Airline object
    A8AirlineAircraftData airline = new A8AirlineAircraftData(airName, airCode, airCraft, firstClass, busiClass, econClass);
    System.out.println(airName + " successfully added. Press Enter to continue.");

    sc.nextLine();
    sc.nextLine();//Press Enter to continue 
    return airline;

}   
}
```

Thank you for any guidance provided. Again, I'm sorry if I'm not being clear or my submission was grammatically incorrect in any way. I try to be concise!

I will now show the changes
**EDIT:**

```
public class A8AirlineAircraftData {

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((airCode == null) ? 0 : airCode.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!(obj instanceof A8AirlineAircraftData)) {
        return false;
    }
    A8AirlineAircraftData other = (A8AirlineAircraftData) obj;
    return Objects.equals(airCode, other.airCode);
}

private String airName; //these are all showing a warning saying 'Field ____ can be final'
private String airCode;
private String airCraft;
private int firstClass;
private int busiClass;
private int econClass;
//public String toStringAirLine(){return "airname is:" + airName + ", aircode is: "+airCode;}

public A8AirlineAircraftData(String airName, String airCode, String airCraft, int firstClass, int busiClass, int econClass) {
    this.airName = airName;
    this.airCode = airCode;
    this.airCraft = airCraft;
    this.firstClass = firstClass;
    this.busiClass = busiClass;
    this.econClass = econClass;
}

public static A8AirlineAircraftData AddAirline(Scanner sc) {
    sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the Airline name:");
    String airName = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter the Airline code:");
    String airCode = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the Delta Aircraft:");
    String airCraft = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the first class seat capacity:");
    int firstClass = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the business class seat capacity:");
    int busiClass = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the economy class seat capacity:");
    int econClass = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Airline name: " + airName);
    System.out.println("Airline code: " + airCode);
    System.out.println("Delta Aircraft: " + airCraft);
    //Splitting the first word from the rest of the string
    String arr[] = airCraft.split(" ", 2);
    String firstWord = arr[0];
    System.out.println(firstWord + " first class seat capacity: " + firstClass);
    System.out.println(firstWord + " business class seat capacity: " + busiClass);
    System.out.println(firstWord + " economy class seat capacity: " + econClass);
    //Airline object
    A8AirlineAircraftData airline = new A8AirlineAircraftData(airName, airCode, airCraft, firstClass, busiClass, econClass);
    Set<A8AirlineAircraftData> aircrafts = new HashSet<>();

    /*for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        aircrafts.add(A8AirlineAircraftData.AddAirline(sc));
    } */

    System.out.println(airName + " successfully added. Press Enter to continue.");

    sc.nextLine();
    sc.nextLine();//Press Enter to continue 
    return airline;
```

Comment: Yes, a `Set` is a collection that does not allow duplicates, so you could have a static `HashSet<String>`, check if the `airCode` already is in the set. If it is not, proceed normally, and then add the `airCode` to the set.

Answer (score 2):

You could invoke your factory method and store the created object in a `Set` such as.
For example to create 3 elements, you could write :

```
Set<A8AirlineAircraftData> aircrafts = new HashSet<>();
for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
   aircrafts.add(A8AirlineAircraftData.AddAirline());
}
```

> I'm not to allow any duplicates of airCode, would HashSet handle that
>   in some way?

Uniqueness of elements in a `Set` relies on the `equals()`/`hashCode()` methods of elements that it contains.
You should so override them in `A8AirlineAircraftData` to rely on the class field that identify in a unique way an instance : `airCode`.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((airCode == null) ? 0 : airCode.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (!(obj instanceof A8AirlineAircraftData))
        return false;
    A8AirlineAircraftData other = (A8AirlineAircraftData) obj;
    return Objects.equal(airCode, other.airCode);
}
```

Comment: I am receiving a `cannot find symbol' error for 'Objects.equal(airCode, other.airCode);` specifically `Objects`

Comment: You probably use a JDK version below 1.7. It is rather old.

Comment: I believe I am on JDK 1.7 for NetBeans 8.0.2. Okay I just needed to import the correct java utility object

Comment: Note that the compiler version used by the IDE may differ to the installed JDK version. Anyway, you can replace this part by :  `return (airCode != null && airCode.equals(other.airCode));`

Comment: I am going to edit my post to show the changes, would you let me know if this looks okay? Also how I might call the returned set?

Comment: Sure. But the best way is you write your own answer.

Comment: I understand, It would help me understand the code once I see an output from my main menu class. That way i can follow the logic via result. Also The for loop at the bottom, I'm not sure if I placed it in the correct area, but it was just running the program multiple times

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161550/discussion-between-davidxxx-and-j-ben).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, Set is an interface for implementations of Set Objects, that do not allow duplicates. In your code airCode is a String, so no duplicate Strings will be allowed in it.
In order to access the variable or method outside of class, you have to set up a correct access modifier for the variable. i.e. public will let this variable be accessible from any other class.

```
public static Set<String> setOfAirCodes = new HashSet<>();
```

regarding other modifiers, read here: [access modifiers in java](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_access_modifiers.htm)